# Snowflake scalar UDF returns Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Tags: user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are doing DataWarehousing work using JDE as a SOurce and Snowflake as the DW.  As such we need to have normal dates in many of the fields that currently have JDE_Julian dates.
Currently, if we have 6 dates that need to be converted in a query, we have to tie to our Date dimension table 6 times (Snowflake does fine with this), but we are looking for a much cleaner solution in the form of a UDF function that just returns the date for a given JDE_Julian_Date.  We have come up with this but are receiving the dreaded "**SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated**"
I have produced the issue here.  Unfortunately, It looks like a **SnowFlake Bug to me**.  But I am open to any insight that doesn't force me to make 6 joins to the lookup table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE mydd (day date, JDE_Julian INT);
INSERT INTO mydd
VALUES
('2017-01-01',117001),
('2017-01-02',117002),
('2017-01-03',117003);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE mySource (id INT, j1 INT);
INSERT INTO mySource
VALUES
(1,117002),
(2,117002),
(3,117003),
(4,117001);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jdetest(julian_date_in int)
  RETURNS date
  VOLATILE
  COMMENT = 'Convert JDE Julian date to regular Date'
  AS
  $$
  SELECT day FROM mydd
      WHERE JDE_Julian = julian_date_in        
  $$;

SELECT jdetest(117001);  --Works
SELECT jdetest(117002);  --Works
SELECT id, jdetest(j1) b1 FROM mysource;  --Fails
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function must guarantee that only a single value is returned.  If you make it an aggregate or something, then Snowflake will know that only 1 value is being returned, instead of a possible recordset.  Try this, it worked for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jdetest(julian_date_in int)
  RETURNS date
  VOLATILE
  COMMENT = 'Convert JDE Julian date to regular Date'
  AS
  $$
  SELECT max(day) as day FROM mydd
      WHERE JDE_Julian = julian_date_in        
  $$;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, IMO. In addition, if you do not like the idea of using MAX() in this way, you can use Snowflake's ANY_VALUE() function instead. In other words, "...SELECT ANY_VALUE(day) as day...".

Comment: Thanks @Mike, it works but not sure why we need a max like function. Looks like an unconventional approach here

Comment: The function can only return 1 value, so it needs to have an aggregate of some kind to ensure that 1 value will only ever be returned.  As @DarrenGardner mentions above, that aggregate could also be ANY_VALUE(), since you don't really have a case where the select will return more than 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the return type to table type as below and it should work.

```
 RETURNS TABLE(val date)
 VOLATILE
 COMMENT = 'Convert JDE Julian date to regular Date'
 AS
 $$
 SELECT day FROM mydd
     WHERE JDE_Julian = julian_date_in        
 $$;


SELECT s.id, f.val AS b1 FROM mysource s
JOIN TABLE(jdetest( s.j1)) f
```

Comment: It's not really a table that is being returned, though, so making it a UDTF over-complicates the request.  Insuring a single value return makes this easier.