# Snowflake Query calling UDF throws "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

Found the solution to the issue in this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866882/snowflake-scalar-udf-returns-unsupported-subquery-type-cannot-be-evaluated?rq=2).  Final implementation for me was adding BOOLAND_AGG to the SELECT like so:

```
-- UDF Definition
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_UDF(col1_in INTEGER, col2_in INTEGER)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS
$$
    SELECT BOOLAND_AGG(my_boolean) FROM FIRST_MATCH
        WHERE col1 = col1_in
        AND col2 = col2_in
$$
;
```

I'm attempting to utilize a Snowflake User Defined Function (UDF) in the where clause of this select statement and have been running into the error message:

> Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated.

I tried testing it by pulling the query out of the UDF and using it as a subquery but am seeing the same issues. UDFs are stated to be usable in where clauses in the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-scalar-functions#using-udfs-in-different-clauses), so not sure where I'm going wrong here.  Thanks!

```
-- Query with UDF
SELECT * FROM FINAL_MATCH_TABLE as FMT
WHERE MY_UDF(FMT.col1, FMT.col2) = TRUE;

-- UDF Definition
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_UDF(col1_in INTEGER, col2_in INTEGER)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS
$$
    SELECT my_boolean FROM FIRST_MATCH
        WHERE col1 = col1_in
        AND col2 = col2_in
$$
;

-- Query with UDF replaced by subquery
SELECT * FROM FINAL_MATCH_TABLE as FMT
WHERE (SELECT my_boolean FROM FIRST_MATCH as FM
        WHERE FM.col1 = FMT.col1
        AND FM.col2 = FMT.col2)= TRUE;
```

Comment: It’s probably because the SQL statement in your UDF is not guaranteed to return a single value - based on the structure of the statement rather than any data the table might hold

Comment: Answer in NickW's comment and the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866882/snowflake-scalar-udf-returns-unsupported-subquery-type-cannot-be-evaluated?rq=2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use '= TRUE' or '= FALSE' to compare boolean values.
So you have to change the query as below

```
-- Query with UDF
SELECT * FROM FINAL_MATCH_TABLE as FMT
WHERE MY_UDF(FMT.col1, FMT.col2);

-- Query with UDF replaced by subquery
SELECT * FROM FINAL_MATCH_TABLE as FMT
WHERE (SELECT my_boolean FROM FIRST_MATCH as FM
    WHERE FM.col1 = FMT.col1
    AND FM.col2 = FMT.col2);
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI you could implement this as a join and not a sub-query -- might be faster in some cases.  Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM FINAL_MATCH_TABLE as FMT
JOIN FIRST_MATCH FM ON FM.col1 = FMT.col1 
                   AND FM.col2 = FMT.col2
                   AND FM.my_boolean = TRUE
```